# Proof of $t=s\vdash ^{v} A\leftrightarrow B$ in First order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

First of all, I will explain my terminology\synthax.

$T\vdash ^{v}\varphi $ if $M\vdash T \Rightarrow M\vdash \varphi $

(where $M\vdash \varphi $ means that for every assignment $v$ in $M$ we have $M,v\vdash T$, therefore $M,v\vdash A$ for every $A\in T$).

and

$T\vdash ^{t}\varphi $ if $M,v\vdash T \Rightarrow M,v\vdash \varphi $

The difference between $\vdash^{t}$ and $\vdash^{v}$ is that $T\vdash^{t} \varphi $ means that $\forall M\forall v (M,v\vDash T \rightarrow M,v\vDash \varphi)$,
and $T\vdash^{v} \varphi$ means that $\forall M(\forall v (M,v\vDash T)\rightarrow \forall v (M,v\vDash \varphi$))

---

I already proved that $t=s\vdash ^{t} A\leftrightarrow B$

When $B$ derived from $A$ by changing some appearances of $t$ with $s$, **only if** there is no bounded variables of $t$ in $A$ and no variable of $s$ is not getting bounded after the change.

Now, I need to prove that -

$t=s\vdash ^{v} A\leftrightarrow B$

when $B$ derived from $A$ by changing some appearances of $t$ with $s$

(In that case, the conditions about when it's ok to change the variables are weaker)

---

My attempt to solve:

Assume $M\vDash t=s$. We will prove that $M\vDash A\leftrightarrow B$ where $B$ derived from $A$ by changing some $t$'s with $s's. Therefore... (Here i'm stuck)

Comment: Where do comes form this "syntax"; it seems to me that $T ⊢^v \varphi$ is "$\varphi$ follows from $T$ in $M$", i.e. **if** for every assignment $v$ in $M$ we have: $M,v ⊢ \sigma$, for every $\sigma \in T$, then $M,v ⊢ \varphi$.

Comment: You right. It's only about semantics.

Comment: If so, we have to use : $\vDash$.

Comment: Which proof system are you using (or which textbook)? This will affect the answer.  Also, it seems that $\vdash^t$ implies $\vdash^v$ automatically, because $(\forall x)[(A(x) \to B(x)]$ implies $(\forall x)A(x) \to (\forall x)B(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Although in general $\vdash^v$ and $\vdash^t$ behave differently,
as the following case shows:

$$x=x^2 \vdash^v y = y^2\quad \text{/* does hold */}$$

$$x=x^2 \vdash^t y = y^2\quad \text{/* does not hold */}$$

For the substition of equals by equals they yield the same result
on different grounds:

$$t = s \vdash^v A(t) \leftrightarrow A(s)\quad \text{/* does hold */}$$

$$t = s \vdash^t A(t) \leftrightarrow A(s)\quad \text{/* does hold */}$$